# Malloc and Assignment inside another function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I need help to understand why this is not working.

I'm trying to `malloc` and assign instructions and separators through another function. With everything I have tried, I get a **segmentation fault** on the second assignment `*separators[1] = '1'`, but for some reason, `*separators = '2'` works.

I think there is something I don't understand with referenced pointers.

---

### Here is my simplified code

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void        split_instructions(char ***instructions, char **separators)
{
    int split_len = 2;

    *instructions = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * split_len + 1);
    if (*instructions == NULL)
        return;
    *separators = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * split_len + 1);
    if (*separators == NULL)
    {
        free(instructions);
        return;
    }
    *separators[0] = (char)'q';
    *separators[1] = (char)'1';
    //*separators = "22"; <- this work
    *instructions[0] = (char*)"test";
    *instructions[1] = (char*)"test2";
}

int main(void)
{
   char **instructions;
   char *separators;
   
   split_instructions(&instructions, &separators);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions like

```
*separators[1] = (char)'1';
```

won't work well due to the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The `[]` operator has higher precedence than `*` operator, so it will try to write to the 2nd element of `separators` while there is only one element for the "array" pointed at by that.

It should be written like

```
(*separators)[1] = (char)'1';
```

Also note that the allocation size in

```
*instructions = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * split_len + 1);
```

looks weird. The `+ 1` will increase the allocation size by only one byte, not size of one element. If you should allocate for another element, it should be

```
*instructions = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (split_len + 1));
```

or

```
*instructions = malloc(sizeof(**instructions) * (split_len + 1));
```

Note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Thank your so much ! That was the point ! The parentheses solves my case. Concerning the malloc it was a mistake. Also thank your the advice about cast